# Getting current LR for tf.train.exponential_decay

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training with exponential weight decay similar to the example from Tensorflow docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/exponential_decay) :

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
starter_learning_rate = 0.1
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step,
                                       100000, 0.96, staircase=True)
# Passing global_step to minimize() will increment it at each step.
learning_step = (
    tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    .minimize(...my loss..., global_step=global_step)
)
```

How I can get a current learning rate during training (e.g to print it out)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call it at `run` time:

```
_, loss, lr = sess.run([learning_step, model_loss, learning_rate], feed_dict={...})
```

You could also plot its evolution with [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard)